# Excel to word VBA for mail merge

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, mailmerge

I have a mail merge I'm attempting to do but I can't find any information on how to update existing merge fields from VBA code. I have 10 labels on each page but each label needs to be processed as a block before moving to the next record as they have to pull from multiple columns to fill out the label. So I need to be able to replace Merge field values with what I have stored in the array. creating a new page of labels every 10 like a normal mail merge would.

I have thought about several approaches but nothing seems to be panning out for me.

I started by trying just a normal mail merge but I was only able to get the left side of the page to populate properly populating the right side causes the data to jump to the next record at the wrong time and there doesn't seem to be a way to go back a record. I couldn't find a way to process the label as a range or block.

After that I tried to reference the field codes directly. with this code but it returns an error that it's read only.

```
Sub OpenExcelFile()

    
    Dim oExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim oWB As Workbook
    Dim RowLoc As Integer
    Dim ExcelArray(1 To 10000, 1 To 6) As Variant
    
    RowLoc = 1
    
    Set oExcel = New Excel.Application
    Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\ScottCannon\Documents\Sticker Maker.xlsm")
    oExcel.Visible = True
    Do While oWB.Sheets("Barcode").Cells(RowLoc, 1) <> ""
        ExcelArray(RowLoc, 1) = oWB.Sheets("Barcode").Cells(RowLoc, 1)
        ExcelArray(RowLoc, 2) = oWB.Sheets("Barcode").Cells(RowLoc, 2)
        ExcelArray(RowLoc, 3) = oWB.Sheets("Barcode").Cells(RowLoc, 3)
        ExcelArray(RowLoc, 4) = oWB.Sheets("Barcode").Cells(RowLoc, 4)
        ExcelArray(RowLoc, 5) = oWB.Sheets("Barcode").Cells(RowLoc, 5)
        ExcelArray(RowLoc, 6) = oWB.Sheets("Barcode").Cells(RowLoc, 6)
        RowLoc = RowLoc + 1
    Loop
    
    RowLoc = 1
    ActiveDocument.MailMerge.DataSource.DataFields("Job_Name").Value = ExcelArray(RowLoc, 1) 'this part specifically doesn't work. 
    oWB.Close
    Excel.Application.Quit
    
End Sub
```

I tried to see if there was a way to create references I can replace, but it seems like if I managed to do that it would only work for a single page. This seems so stupid it should let you group cells together as a single object or something.

Comment: A properly-configured label merge in Word will do all of that with no code, so why are you doing it this way?

Comment: I explained pretty thoroughly in the question. I've tried several different approaches. When I attempt to make it a standard mail merge I can only get half of the page to populate, because of the way mail merges process (left to right row by row) I cannot have fields to the right because there is no way to go back and forth between records only forward.

So my first line would be correct for the first label then the second label would have the correct first line, but the second line for the first label would be data from the second label because it already moved to the next record

Comment: I suppose I should explain these labels are not standard mailing labels they are fairly complex. They have a company logo and generate a barcode. I need the label to be formatted so that varying lengths of data in the field will not change the location of the data. 

the best way I found to get the label to look proper is to split the cell down to 3 x 4 and use them to contain the data. but that presents the problem I described. I just want each 3x4 grid to be it's own label. If everything is in one cell I don't see how I can keep the formatting correct.

Comment: No, you did not explain why you can't use Word's mailmerge tools. All you did is describe what you're trying to do via VBA. You could use a table with nested cells, which it appears you're now doing, or a Directory merge. For the latter, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/114940-post2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved my own problem. creating the labels as normal (with each label being it's own cell of a table.) I can insert a table into each cell and that will allow each label to have completely customizable formatting while still treating each label individually. So I can insert the barcode I need and the company logo without worry that text from other areas is going to screw up the formatting.